# How do I install many lines of packages with apt (from a script)? Does '\' work?

Tags: bash, script, apt

A part of my Bash script looks like this:

```
apt install -y alsa-base alsa-utils apt-transport-https build-essential curl ffmpeg geany gcc \
gnome-screenshot gnome-terminal libfuse2 libreoffice-calc libssl-dev network-manager \
nftables openssh-client pkg-config pulseaudio pypy pypy3 racket redshift rsync transmission-cli \
transmission-common transmission-daemon ufw unzip x11-xserver-utils xinit xterm
```

Does it work with `\` or do I have to put everything in one line?